# Custom product type with variation, variation name not show in cart/checkout

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I created a CUSTOM product type variation, everything works good in backend and front end, the only problem is, in the shopping cart / Checkout details, the variable product name not showing, also after purchase item the stock is not reducing, 1 item available for the variable, after purchase, keep the 1 item available instead of out of stock.

This is the code used.

````
 * Step 1. Add a custom product type "term" to other hardcoded ones
 */
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'misha_ticket_product_type' );
 
function misha_ticket_product_type( $product_types ){
    $product_types[ 'ticket' ] = 'Ticket';
    return $product_types;
}
 
/**
 * Step 2. Each product type has a PHP class WC_Product_{type}
 */
add_action( 'init', 'misha_create_ticket_product_class' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'misha_load_ticket_product_class',10,2);
 
function misha_create_ticket_product_class(){
    class WC_Product_Ticket extends WC_Product_Variable {


        public function __construct( $product ) {

            $this->product_type = 'ticket';
            $this->supports[]   = 'ajax_add_to_cart';
            parent::__construct( $product );
           
        }

        public function get_type() {
            return 'ticket'; // so you can use $product = wc_get_product(); $product->get_type()
        }
            
    }
}


add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs','ticket_showtabs',10,1);
 function ticket_showtabs($tabs) {

            array_push($tabs['attribute']['class'], 'show_if_variable', 'show_if_ticket');
            array_push($tabs['variations']['class'], 'show_if_ticket');
        
          return $tabs;

        }  

function producttype_custom_js() {

if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
    return;
endif;

?><script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery("body").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
   jQuery(this).find('.enable_variation').addClass('show_if_ticket').show();
});

</script><?php 
} 

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'producttype_custom_js' ,99);
 
function misha_load_ticket_product_class( $php_classname, $product_type ) {
    if ( $product_type == 'ticket' ) {
        $php_classname = 'WC_Product_Ticket';
    }
    return $php_classname;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', function( $stores ){
    $stores['product-ticket'] = 'WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
} ); 
    
add_action( 'woocommerce_ticket_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart' );

//**************************************END*********************************//```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, and it occurs because `woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler` expects `get_type` to return `'variable'` in order to trigger the `add_to_cart_handler_variable` method.

```
function misha_custom_add_to_cart_handler( $handler, $adding_to_cart ){
    if( $handler == 'ticket' ){
        $handler = 'variable';
    }
    return $handler;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'misha_custom_add_to_cart_handler', 10, 2 );
```

You would need something like the above as per discussion here [How to add a custom WooCommerce product type that extends WC_Product_Variable to the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316906/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type-that-extends-wc-product-variable-to)